# write to a postgresql database table or csv file? Which is faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, csv

I have created a python script that is currently inserting 15,000,000 rows into a database table. I have calculated that this is going to take 6 days. It is currently at 2,000,000 rows with 3 columns of type VARCHAR, BOOLEAN, SMALLINT. I want to know, would it have been faster to write 15 million rows to a csv file and then import the csv file to create the database table. I don't want to cancel the current process just in case its just the same. I am now 16 hours in.

Comment: The short answer is "yes."  Try it in another database while the current load is running.

Comment: Can you give me a rough estimate of the time it might take please. By rough estimate I mean will it take hours or days? The script is running from within Pycharm and a venv so running a second instance would require creating a new venv, modifying the code, installing the necessary dependencies, creating the database and the table.

Comment: where is your python script getting the data from? Where is your database (local/remote)? What would the filesize of the csv file be? There are many variables to answer this question.

Comment: The data is a local csv file. The Python script is modifying the data to the format I need and creating around 15 million network numbers from 224 network ranges and sending each individual network number to the database. The database is also local.

Comment: 6 days? How many terabyte are you going to write? Are you using single INSERT statements or COPY? The last one is lighting fast

Comment: are you using COPY command rather than insert? Using COPY you can get pretty close to your read/write speed of the hard drive/SSD where your db resides

Comment: I am using single insert commands

Comment: Single INSERT = slow. Check copy and how to use it. Not sure what adapter you're using, but this one works fine: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from

Comment: Could you also tell us what your script is doing? Maybe you could create your content completely inside the database, using a single query. And usually you would store a network address in datatype INET, not in a VARCHAR.

Comment: My script is reading network numbers assigned by IANA. Removing any leading 0's and removing "/8". Filtering out any ranges assigned to any defense, i.e DoD, DOD, Army, Intelligence, removing any RESERVED. With the remaining ranges I am generating every single network number, so three octets or 24 bit network numbers and writing them to a database. I have now stopped the program and created a csv writer but when I try to import some data to my postgresql database I am getting an error.

Comment: --command " "\\copy public.ip_store (network_number, scanned_status, number_of_scans) FROM 'C:/Users/jhowd/Desktop/NETWOR~1.CSV' DELIMITER ',' CSV ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong datatype, an INET doesn't store a leading 0 when you try to put a leading 0 to the network address. I also think you could do it by using a single query that does all the work your script is doing. About the error, please update your question with relevant information.

Comment: The speed you describe is vastly slower than what a single-row insert is capable of.  There is some dramatic bottleneck here, but based on your description we can't know what it is.  Are you committing each insert separately?  What indexes do you have? Constraints?  Triggers? Is the python script running on the same host that is running the database?

Answer (score 0):

On the speed of INSERT:

Every query your client program executes results in communication over the network, or a unix socket on localhost, which incurs some overhead.

Also, and this is very important, if you use autocommit and don't wrap a ton of INSERTs inside a transaction, then each INSERT will be in its own transaction and postgres will not acknowledge to the client that the INSERT is done until the data has been written to the disk in a manner that guarantees that it will still be there if the server crashes. This flushing to disk obviously takes a while, on rotational disks expect at least 10 milliseconds, less for SSDs but still it's not zero. You really don't want to do it for each INSERT if you do a lot of them, so the first thing to do would be to wrap the whole thing in a BEGIN/COMMIT so it runs in a single transaction.

Then the next thing to do would be INSERT INTO ... VALUES () and put tons of values in there, not just one row, so the query overhead is amortized over many rows.

> With the remaining ranges I am generating every single network number, so three octets or 24 bit network numbers and writing them to a database.

So the obvious next optimization is to generate the ranges on the server. For example

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1)
...lots of INSERTS...
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (100)
```

This will be faster:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (1),(2),...lots of values...,(100)
```

This will be even faster, but COPY still has to parse all the data:

```
\copy table (column) FROM stdin
1
2
...etc
```

And this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) SELECT n FROM generate_series(1,100) n;
```

will be even faster still since it won't have to parse all that text into values, it'll just generate them. If you want to insert ranges, and you do that with a loop on the client, replace the loop with a generate_series on the server.

Next, if you don't need to actually store every ip address, but are only interested in ranges, then why not store the ranges directly instead of all the ip's? Postgres has a RANGE feature. This would also massively reduce the size of the table.

Next you can use an UNLOGGED table to speed up your insertions. It won't have crash recovery, which means postgres doesn't bother writing the recovery log data to disk, which speeds up INSERTs and UPDATEs quite a lot. You can always switch it back to LOGGED once all the data is generated, so it survives a crash.

Next, create the indexes after inserting all the data. It is much faster to create an index from scratch than to build it bit by bit as data is inserted.

I just found [this](https://dzone.com/articles/awesome-one-liner-postgresql). So,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_ips(cidr)
RETURNS SETOF inet LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
$$
 select $1 + s from generate_series(1,  broadcast($1) - (network($1)) - 1) s;
$$;

BEGIN;
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE foo (ip INET NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO foo SELECT all_ips('10.0.0.0/8');
COMMIT;
```

This 16 million rows INSERT takes 44s on a Core 2 Quad from 2008. It uses mostly CPU, probably in the internal INET/CIDR functions, which means you can run one of these per CPU core in parallel, for more speed..

```
CREATE INDEX foo_ip ON foo(ip);
```

takes an additional 17 seconds,

```
ALTER TABLE foo SET LOGGED;
```

takes about a minute, as it has to write about a gigabyte of table and index to the WAL.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I wrote 13.6 million lines to a csv file and used pgadmin to import the file.